# How do i grep another file, if one file path at the same location is mentioned?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, grep

Suppose I have a file at location /var/log/abc.txt and another file at same location /var/log/xyz.txt. But in my program i have mentioned /var/log/abc.txt location.. now using same location how can i use the xyz.txt file without specifying the location of it. 
I want my command to cut abc.txt and replace with xyz.txt

Comment: What it means `I want my command to cut abc.txt and replace with xyz.txt` and why to use grep for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dirname /var/log/abc.txt
```

It return the path /var/log

**Example**

```
oldfile="/var/log/abc.txt"
newfile="$(dirname $oldfile)/xyz.txt"
echo $newfile
```